# Googletrans Bulk translation special character issues

Tags: python, google-translate

I have been trying to send bulk translation requests using googletrans==3.1.0a0 and version 4.0.

I concatenated around 50 short sentences and separated them with special characters (e.g. ';.', '$@' -etc.). Doing so helps me limit the number of request sent to googletranslate saving me time (I have millions of line to translate) at the same time avoid the limit set on the number of requests authorized ( I am not able to set a proxy or user_agent correctly)

```
translator = Translator()
if original_text :
     output = translator.translate(original_text, dest='en')
     translated_text = output.text
```

The results are quite disappointing. I ever run a code to check with are the best special characters combinations that works better. :

```
difference = abs(len(bulk_text_to_translate_list_titles) - len (translated_list_titles))
list_deviation.append(difference )
dicoSpecial[special_char] = sum(list_deviation)
```

Sample of results for requests sent:

```
'£='
Sum:  500
'#,'
Sum:  71
'^>'
Sum:  40
'£%'
Sum:  34
'–['
Sum:  500
'&+'
Sum:  500
':)'
Sum:  20
'%/'
Sum:  500
''*'
```

Any recommendations on how to proceed ?

Thank you,
Bilel

Answer (score 0):

The [googletrans API](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/)  that you are using is the same service as translate.google.com. Google Trans is not intended to translate bulk data.  Documentation of
[googletrans API](https://py-googletrans.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#note-on-library-usage) talks about the following problems

1. The maximum character limit on a single text is 15k.
2. Due to limitations of the web version of google translate, this API does not guarantee that the library would run properly always.

If you want to use a stable API, I recommend you to use [Google’s official translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs).

Steps for Using Translate API

You can check this on how to set up [Translate API](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/setup). Furthermore , You can try this [quickstart](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/quickstart) .
You can browse [this](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/how-to) site for other guides that have sample code.
You can follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52189037/bulk-translation-of-a-big-set-of-records-via-google-translate) for bulk translation

It is advisable to file an issue on [Github](https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/issues) so that the maintainers of the library can improve it.